# Difference of shell execution between command mode and interactive mode

Tags: bash, sudo, wayland, terminal-emulator

The problem. I am doing shell script that running from the desktop launcher, and it failed to execute in certain condition. To express the problem, I very simplify the problem code. The code is very simple:

`uxterm -e bash -c 'echo 1 | sudoedit /etc/fstab'`

It works good when I run it from the terminal emulator, but when I make it launch from the desktop environment, it fails.
Launch from the desktop I mean launching from sway WM with this config

`bindsym Mod4+F10 exec uxterm -e bash -c 'echo 1 | sudoedit /etc/fstab'`

I also tried alacritty terminal emulator, and weston compositor.

When I use `uxterm -e bash path/to/script`, it works good.

What is the difference between launching from the terminal and from the desktop, between -c option and launching script?

I expect smooth launch in any environment, and the most important, I need to know whats wrong here.

EDIT: To be clear, there is my actual script that works with the problem:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

ere-escape() { sed 's/[[^.$()|*+?{\]/\\&/g' ; } ; export -f ere-escape
bre-escape() { sed 's/[[*$\^.]/\\&/g'       ; } ; export -f bre-escape

filelist()
{
    source profile-dirs
    for LAYER in "${PROFILE_LAYERS[@]}"
    do
        find "$PROFILE_DIR/home/$LAYER" -type f -printf '%P\0'  2> /dev/null
        find "$PROFILE_DIR/root/$LAYER" -type f -printf '/%P\0' 2> /dev/null
    done | (
        if [ "$1" ]
            then cd -- "$HOME" && xargs -0 -- grep --null -il -F -e "$1" -- 2> /dev/null
            else cat
        fi
    ) | LC_COLLATE=C sort -z
}
export -f filelist

export SEARCH="/tmp/$(uuidgen)" ; touch "$SEARCH"
filelist |
(
    cd "$HOME" &&
        fzf --header='[ Tab: Select | ^E: Edit | ^R: Search | Alt+u/U: Update | [Alt+]<^>: Preview ]' \
            --read0                                             \
            --layout=reverse-list                               \
            --multi                                             \
            --info=inline                                       \
            --preview-window='33%'                              \
            --preview '
                grep -i --color=always -e "^" -e "$(bre-escape < "$SEARCH")" -- {}
            '                                                   \
            --bind 'focus:transform-preview-label(echo [ {} ])' \
            --bind 'change:change-preview-window(33%)'          \
            --bind 'right:change-preview-window(75%)'           \
            --bind 'left:change-preview-window(33%)'            \
            --bind 'esc:clear-query+clear-selection+close'      \
            --bind 'tab:toggle+down+show-preview'               \
            --bind='ctrl-r:reload(
                printf -- "%s\\n" {q} > "$SEARCH"
                filelist {q}
            )+transform-prompt(echo "&"{q}" > ")+clear-query'   \
            --bind='alt-u:execute(
                clear -x
                echo "Updating user profile..."
                profile-update.sh
                clear -x
                profile-push.sh
                read -n1 -p"Done. Press any key."
            )'                                                  \
            --bind='alt-U:execute(
                clear -x
                echo "Updating root profile..."
                sudo profile-update.sh "root"
                clear -x
                profile-push.sh
                read -n1 -p"Done. Press any key."
            )'                                                  \
            --bind='ctrl-e:execute(
                if [[ {} == /* ]]
                    then sudoedit -- {+}
                    else $EDITOR -- {+}
                fi
            )+clear-selection'                                  \
            --bind 'enter:execute(
                [[ "$PAGER" != less* ]] && exit

                JUMP="$(ere-escape < "$SEARCH" | ere-escape | sed "s/[!@]/\\\\\\\\\\\\&/g")" # Less special char double escaping
                if [ "$JUMP" ]
                    then JUMP="+/${JUMP,,*}"
                    else JUMP="+/^"
                fi

                if [[ {} == /* ]]
                then
                    if [ -r {} ]
                        then SUDO_EDITOR="$EDITOR" LESSEDIT="%E %g" EDITOR="sudoedit" $PAGER --use-backslash "$JUMP" -- {+}
                        else sudoedit -- {+}
                    fi
                else
                    $PAGER --use-backslash "$JUMP" -- {+}
                fi
            )+clear-selection'
)
rm -f "$SEARCH"
```

EDIT: More details discovered. Somehow, editor is not becoming a foreground process.

```bash
# Works good
   PPID     PID    PGID     SID TTY        TPGID STAT   UID   TIME COMMAND
      1  131055  131054  131054 ?             -1 Sl    1000   0:03 alacritty
 131055  131075  131075  131075 pts/0     136428 Ss    1000   0:00  \_ /bin/bash
 131075  136428  136428  131075 pts/0     136428 S+    1000   0:00      \_ /bin/bash /home/user/.my/bin/profile-config.sh
 136428  136432  136428  131075 pts/0     136428 Sl+   1000   0:00          \_ fzf --header=[ Tab: Select | ^E: Edit | ^R: Search | Alt+u/U: Upda...
 136432  136478  136428  131075 pts/0     136428 S+    1000   0:00              \_ /bin/bash -c                  if [[ '/etc/pacman.conf' == /* ]] ...
 136478  136479  136428  131075 pts/0     136428 S+       0   0:00                  \_ sudoedit -- /etc/pacman.conf
 136479  136480  136480  136480 pts/1     136481 Ss       0   0:00                      \_ sudoedit -- /etc/pacman.conf
 136480  136481  136481  136480 pts/1     136481 Sl+   1000   0:00                          \_ nvim -p /var/tmp/pacmanJYcL0eJF.conf
 136481  136484  136484  136484 ?             -1 Ssl   1000   0:00                              \_ nvim --embed -p /var/tmp/pacmanJYcL0eJF.conf

# Not working:
   PPID     PID    PGID     SID TTY        TPGID STAT   UID   TIME COMMAND
      1  136493  136492  136492 ?             -1 S     1000   0:00 /bin/bash /home/user/.config/sway/hotkeys.sh profile_config
 136493  136495  136492  136492 ?             -1 Sl    1000   0:00  \_ alacritty -e /bin/bash -c          ttitle.sh "${1##*/}"  ...
 136495  136516  136516  136516 pts/2     136516 Ss+   1000   0:00      \_ /bin/bash -c          ttitle.sh "${1##*/}"         ...
 136516  136521  136516  136516 pts/2     136516 S+    1000   0:00          \_ /bin/bash profile-config.sh
 136521  136528  136516  136516 pts/2     136516 S+    1000   0:00              \_ /bin/bash profile-config.sh
 136528  136575  136516  136516 pts/2     136516 S+       0   0:00                  \_ sudoedit -- /etc/pacman.conf
 136575  136580  136580  136580 pts/3     136580 Ss+      0   0:00                      \_ sudoedit -- /etc/pacman.conf
 136580  136581  136581  136580 pts/3     136580 Sl    1000   0:00                          \_ nvim -p /var/tmp/pacmanvJESy88R.conf
 136581  136584  136584  136584 ?             -1 Ssl   1000   0:00                              \_ nvim --embed -p /var/tmp/pacmanvJESy88R.conf
```

You can see that sudoedit stays as foreground process (stat Ss+).

Comment: Why would you attach the stdout of `echo 1` to the stdin of `sudoedit`?

Comment: (To be clear, `path/to/script` contains the exact text `echo 1 | sudoedit /etc/fstab`, or anything else?)

Comment: (It's _possible_ that sway's parsing and quote-removal code isn't identical to the shell's, but without knowing its implementation that's just speculation)

Comment: > Why would you attach the stdout of echo 1 to the stdin of sudoedit?


It's due to simplification. See whole script that I attached in main question. It for running sudoedit from the subshell

Comment: yes, path/to/script contains the exact text echo 1 | sudoedit /etc/fstab

Comment: Your regexp escaping code is wrong, see [is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed), and you're using twice as many backslashes in `sed "s/[!@]/\\\\\\\\\\\\&/g"` as you need due to using the wrong quotes, use single quotes unless you NEED double quotes (which you don't in this case). Also, are you sure you want to do `ere-escape < "$SEARCH" | ere-escape`?

Comment: I'm absolutely sure for these lines of code. In this case, less requires double escaping. There is a better solution: turn off regexp at all by adding ^R at the beginning of search pattern.

Comment: What do you mean by _it failed to execute_? Returning no error message, but a non-zero exit code?